# Python, delete subinterval from an interval

Tags: python, range

In python, I have an interval

```
a = 1-100
```

And I have a list with intervals

```
b = [11-20,41-50,91-110]
```

Now I would like my output to be like this in python:

```
a-b = 1-10,21-40,51-90
```

Comment: `1-100` is not a range, but an `int` literal which equals to `-99`

Comment: I am not sure what you *think* you are doing, but what you are *actually doing* is setting `a = -99`, then `b = [-9, -9, -19]`, and trying to get `a-b` to be equal to the tuple `(-9, -19, -39)`

Comment: It is an interval given as a hyphenated form.Why is it is difficult to understand and why would someone downvote the question, if you couldn't think out of box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this :

```
a=range(1,100)
b = [range(11,20),range(41,50),range(91,110)] #list of ranges
```

So you can try :

```
d=[]
i=a.start 
for sub_range in b: #for each sub range
    #get the start and stop
    start=sub_range.start 
    end=sub_range.stop
    #append range to list
    d.append(range(i,start-1))
    i=end+1

print(d)
[range(1, 10), range(21, 40), range(51, 90)]
```

Comment: Thanks Sruthi! It's a really good answer. The only caveat is that the sub_range list needs to be inside the range. But this gave me a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
a = range(1,101)
set(a)
 b = [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100]
set(a)-set(b)
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90}
```

You can use more_itertoools to divide the list

```
import more_itertools as mit
iterable = list(d)
[list(group) for group in mit.consecutive_groups(iterable)]
```

Result

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40], [51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90]]
```